# React-Typescript - 'rafce' shortcut not working in VS Code

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript

I was install the React snippets extension in VSCode using with this link:->**https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets**
After i add the extension.But ***i want typescript extension command***, when i did used ***rafce*** it's only use for creating normal functional component only,What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Under - Visual Studio Code,
Click on "Extensions" button from left bar last one / Ctrl + Shift + X (by shortcut),
Search - 'react snippets',
Install - ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets.
Done - now 'rafce' shortcut will work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBqrx.jpg)

- Thank You.